# Automatically playing a DVD movie?

Tags: dvd, autoplay, video-playback

I have set up Autoplay to launch Media Player Upon insertion of a DVD movie in my DVD/CD R/W. I have set all of the defaults for Media Player. It always used to play properly. Now the only way that I get a movie to play is to open up media player manually and then select the movie that is currently residing in the DVD drive. Everything works properly is then – except for the Autoplay.

What am I missing?

Comment: What version of Windows?

Answer (score 2):

For Windows 7: `Control Panel` -> `Autoplay` and select Play using Windows Media Player for default for a video DVD.

Comment: already did/tried that. It simply does not work. Aargh!!

Comment: http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/fix-dvd-play-error-windows-cannot-access-the-specified-device-windows-7/    -- This provides for access through Computer but does not provide for Autoplay access(that is, I still have to do something instead of merely inserting a new movie in my DVD – but at least I'm getting there. Slowly, but surely!)

Comment: http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/fix-dvd-play-error-windows-cannot-access-the-specified-device-windows-7/    forgot URL,  sorry!!

Answer (score 0):

And I found the answer! I don't know how it happened but apparently I 
actually had AutoRun turned off for the CD/DVD drives. Information about the 
two registry settings that control AutoRun can be found in this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144204%28v=vs.85%29.aspx